# Redirect to Different URl on validation errors in form builder

Tags: 8, forms

I am using drupal 8 fapi and i have user case as below

I have a form  on https://example.com/landing-page and I submit the  form and there are validation errors .the page should reload as https://example.com/landing-page#lead-form.

Is there any hack we can implement?

I came with logic

if validation has error set form redirect page to example.com/landing-page#lead-form

```
if($form_state->getErrors() ) {
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('example.com/landing-page#lead-form');
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

some how its not working.

Is there any way we can change the url to example.com/landing-page#lead-form and show the validation error at same time .

Comment: @jaypan if you can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

For Internal:

```
global $base_url;
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($base_url.'/landing-page#lead-form');
// You can use any one of these below to show error message.
$form_state->setError($element, $message);
$form_state->setErrorByName($element, $message);
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

For External:
Use full link

```
$response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://facebook.com');
// You can use any one of these below to show error message.
$form_state->setError($element, $message);
$form_state->setErrorByName($element, $message);
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EnforcedResponseException to terminate form processing and redirect:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('user.login', [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString());
throw new \Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException($response);
```

For external urls use TrustedRedirectResponse not RedirectResponse:

```
$response = TrustedRedirectResponse('http://www.google.com');
throw new \Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException($response);
```